# I believe a publisher is infringing copyright when reproducing a figure I created. What can I do?

Tags: copyright, graphics, publishers, legal-issues, elsevier

A few months ago an Elsevier representative contacted me asking for permission to reproduce one of my thesis figures in one of their books. Since this figure is only in my thesis (introduction section) and is not published elsewhere, I retain full copyright.

Because I am truly concerned about the negative effect of Elsevier policies on science at large, I am boycotting Elsevier. I considered not granting them permission, however I thought that this would mostly affect the authors of the book and have very little effect on Elsevier. I asked my Facebook contacts what I should do, and one of them proposed a very nice solution. Basically, he suggested that I publish the work under some terms so that everyone, and not only Elsevier, can be directed to the specific conditions under which this work can be reused. So I posted my figure on [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/record/1247978#.W7hZXxShRf8) (this actually makes sense because I have been asked many times for permission to reproduce this figure - mind you, that's the only reason why my thesis gets cited at all).

I replied to the Elsevier representative referring him to the Zenodo entry, and specifically letting him know that the modified version of the figure that they want to use does not comply with my terms (since it removes the text stating I own the copyright).

Last week, I noticed that a preview of the book is available in Google Books. To my surprise, I noticed that the [version of the figure (fig. 11.1)](https://books.google.fi/books?hl=en&lr=&id=U0JvDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA351&ots=GGENABkYai&sig=1HnVtY755whGO-sdAN1zClPOQnU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) that they ended up using does not comply with the terms I communicated to the Elsevier representative. What can/should I do about this?

**Edit**

I contacted the Elsevier representative who apologized and corrected the image. The Google Books link above now shows the copyright notice as it should (hopefully this settles the nonsensical debate initiated by @user71659 depicting increasingly weird scenarios in which Elsevier had recompiled the figure from scratch).

Comment: The first question would be if your diagram is copyright protected at all in the countries where that book is sold. If some work is protected by copyright in the USA (for example) it does not mean that the work is also protected in Russia. In this case it would be legal to modify the diagram and sell the book in Russia. (I've heard that musicians had this problem some years ago when you could legally download copied music from Russian servers...)

Comment: @MartinRosenau Not sure where you read this, but I don't think it works that way. Russia is under the [Berne convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), so copyright protection is automatic and does not require a registration.

Comment: @Dawn No, see my reply. They probably took it from my website.

Comment: @Miguel Then give us the actual link in the question. That's critical information you've failed to give.

Comment: @user71659 The way the colors are rendered looks like they extracted it from my thesis (old version of that figure) and then used inkscape or similar to change the fonts. The public version of my thesis is here: https://cora.ucc.ie/handle/10468/1344

Comment: @Miguel Page number?

Comment: @user71659 27 of PDF or 2 in "printed" version.

Comment: @Miguel That's the exact same figure you linked to! You haven't shown anything different. If the data is not copyrightable, there is no problem extracting it from your figure. You can't copyright the fact that 530 nm = green.

Comment: @user71659 The Elsevier person sent me an email with the exact same figure that they published in the book (a derivative of mine, not "just the data") asking for permission to reproduce it. I granted conditional permission. They modified the figure, not "extracted the data". I can even forward the email to you if it serves to settle this nonsense.

Comment: @Miguel You haven't shown anything. They asked for permission. You put conditions. Assume they didn't agree with them, so they recreated the plot using elements that were uncopyrightable. How did this scenario not happen? Again, you need to get a lawyer to explain to you whether copyright infringement did actually happen, because what you think is copyrightable may not be.

Comment: They are also giving you credit in that link that you share. I'm confused as to what the issue is at this point.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It was at the end of the 1990: According to Russian Laws artistic work in other languages than Russian was not seen as "artistic work" - and therefore not copyrighted. There were music download services that provided English rock music for download...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni As far as I understand correctly the Berne Convention says that some work created in another country and/or by a foreign person must not be less copyright protected compared to the same work created in the country by a citizen of the country. This would mean that it would not be allowed that Russia only protects books of Russian writers but not of US writers. However it would be allowed that Russia generally does not protect physics books if it does neither protect books written by Russians nor by other people.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Maybe it was before 1995, since Russia joined the Berne convention in that year? Also, regarding your second comment: the Berne Convention includes [minimum levels of copyright protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention#The_minimum_standards_of_protection_relate_to_the_works_and_rights_to_be_protected).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni At least I know two prominent examples of something being seen as "copyright protected work" in one country but as "no intellectual property and therefore not copyrightable" in another country: First is the photo of the monkey "Naruto". (Copyright protected in GB, not protected in the US) The second one are two different photos of a red bus which is colored within a black-and-white picture. (The later photo is seen as "copy of the first photo" in GB but as "work not related to the first photo" in DE.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The problem here is that the Berne convention definitely includes minimum levels of copyright protection for protected work but obviously it does not exactly specify what exactly "protected work" is.

Comment: Can you screenshot the two and put them in your post so we can compare more easily?

Comment: @CapeCode great edit, thanks! I didn't like the title either.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You attempted to use a [crayon license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem), that is, modify the terms of an existing well-established license to better suit your needs.

This is frowned upon, because it can cause legal complications. In particular, the license CC-BY-NC 4.0 license that you attached to your work states

> The Licensor shall not be bound by any additional or different terms or conditions communicated by You unless expressly agreed.

or, in other words (human-readable version on their website)

> No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

The CC folks [officially forbid](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-change-the-license-terms-or-conditions) you from using that name and logo if you do modify their terms:

> Can I change the license terms or conditions?
>
> Yes—but if you change the terms and conditions of any Creative Commons license, you must no longer call, label, or describe the license as a “Creative Commons” or “CC” license, nor can you use the Creative Commons logos, buttons, or other trademarks in connection with the modified license or your materials.

So it is going to be difficult to argue for your additional restrictions in court. They are likely to be void. For legal purposes, we can assume that your work is licensed under an unmodified [CC-BY-NC 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/).

Notice 1 still stands, because the CC license allows you to specify your preferred name and wording for the attribution (and it seems to me that they complied with it in the book). Notice 2 is void. Notice 3 still stands, because the license only covers non-commercial use.

So Elsevier is infringing it because they are using it in a commercial work, right? In principle yes, but you wrote that you had an exchange with them and essentially authorized them to use it in the book under the terms listed in Zenodo. We would have to review your full conversation with Elsevier to see what you really wrote to them.

Disclaimer: [IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL).

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. I explicitly told the guy that they should comply with Notice 2. I should also add I have exactly zero intention to take this to court. I'm just wondering if I can annoy them (Elsevier) a bit without annoying the authors too much.

Comment: Exact wording that I used: "At the moment, as I can see from the edited version of the figure which you attached to your email, you do not comply with "copyright notice 2". You are free to use the figure after you fix this."

Comment: I fixed "notice 2". Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Miguel If all you want is to "annoy them a bit", then it's completely unprofessional and you're wasting everybody's time here.

Comment: @BartoszKP Would you say that strike is unprofessional? Taking (legal) action against corporations with abusive policies has been historically a driving force in gaining rights and changing some of those policies.

Comment: @Miguel I'm not talking about actions, but intentions. If people went on a strike just because they want to "annoy someone a bit" it would be unprofessional as well.

Comment: @BartoszKP Well, if it wasn't obvious, my "intention" is for them to take notice that they should not ignore authors rights. You must live inside of my head to know my intentions better than I do.

Comment: @Miguel I'm not living inside your head. I've quoted your words from the very first comment in this thread directly (please note the quotation marks). Sorry if I misunderstood what you meant, but just wanting to annoy someone (your words - not mine) does sound a little childish.

Answer (score 16):

If you think Elsevier is infringing your copyright, then you are infringing on others ([1](https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/semitech_en/kap_2/backbone/r2_3_1.html), [2](http://www-opto.e-technik.uni-ulm.de/lehre/cs/), [3](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/ap216/images/bandgap_engineering/rosette_global.jpg), [4](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/ap216/images/bandgap_engineering/rosette_gan.jpg))

That chart is [very standard](https://www.google.com/search?q=bandgap+vs+lattice+constant). The information itself is uncopyrightable. The only thing that stands out is the rainbow spectrum, but even then you weren't the first to draw it like that, see this [book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511790546) published 2006: [5](https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org/chap21/F21-04%20Semiconduct%20converter.jpg).

I'm sure the people working in the copyright clearance department of Elsevier have far more experience than you, or nearly everybody here, in these matters, who like me, isn't a lawyer.

Comment: They did cite Miguel's thesis, however.

Comment: Elsevier is infringing my copyright because they modified my creation directly. I generated the graph from scratch. Your answer seems contradictory to me. One thing is the information and another the media created. I think you're mixing things up. As a matter of fact the way that band gap interpolation is done differs from previous work, but that's another thing.

Comment: @Miguel not every work is protected by copyright. There's always some hurdle like creative content, originality, etc. Which varies by jurisdiction to some extent. Or in short: **Copyright protection *might* not apply here.**

Comment: @DonQuiKong We are not talking about ideas here. What Elsevier did was, literally, crop my image file and erase a copyright notice I put there. This is why this answer is missing the point.

Comment: @Miguel you're missing the point. Not everything is protected by copyright. Doesn't matter what notice you put on it. In other words, there are images and texts where copyright doesn't apply.

Comment: @DonQuiKong No, what this answer says is not that "not everything is protected by copyright"; what is says is that my work cannot possibly be protected by copyright because the original idea belongs to someone else. To me, this seems like a logical fallacy, simply because I'm not claiming I own copyright on the idea, but on the work itself. Your argument is separate from the tenet of the answer.

Comment: @Miguel it's not a logical fallacy. Your work is protected by copyright if it's original etc. If the idea is known and it's only a simple representation of data it might not be protected.

Comment: @DonQuiKong It's not "a simple representation of data" but something more involved. And you keep saying "may/might" and the answer clearly implies "must".

Comment: @Miguel I don't know if copyright applies here. But you were saying it had to so I explained that, no, it doesn't have to, it depends. Your juggling a lot of legal stuff in this story that you clearly have no idea about so I was trying to broaden your horizon. Just take it or leave it.

Comment: Looking at the two plots, I would bet that Elsevier have *not* modified your creation directly - I think they have recreated it from scratch, as you did. Note the different aspect ratio, the broken x-axis, the different font, etc.

Comment: @Flyto The data used for this plot requires the code I wrote to generate it (or the author writing their own), so it is very unlikely that they have generated it from scratch. Also, why would they ask for permission and cite my thesis if they had generated their own? They may have used the version in my thesis or my website. Other than that, cropping a figure and adding a couple of lines to break the axes is not precisely rocket science.

Comment: @Miguel You say you used a different method to interpolate bandgap. That in itself may not be copyrightable, because it is [not a creative expression](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/can-models-be-protected-by-copyright-law/). Scientific, technical methods and discoveries in the US are [excluded from copyright](https://copyright.gov/circs/circ31.pdf). Your code may be patentable, the code itself falls under copyright, but the output, including equations and figures, are not. I think you're making the assumption that academic plagiarism  is a copyright violation, which is not always true.

Comment: @user71659 Plagiarism is out of the question since they properly reference the work. This is just a copyright issue.

Comment: @Miguel And again, in the United States, it was found that scientific figures from a model [may not have copyright protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho_v._Taflove). You need to get a copyright lawyer to check this _before making accusations_, because you very well may be in the wrong and by making invalid claims, trying to take rights away from others. This could subject you, depending on the country and the law, to a lawsuit.

Comment: @user71659 In the case you mention, https://cases.justia.com/federal/district-courts/illinois/ilndce/1:2007cv04305/211294/120/0.pdf, it is stated in the summary (footnote 6) that the "reused" figures were not direct copies of the original ones. Again, you're talking about two separate things here, the "model" (which is not copyrightable) and the figures (which are). The "expression" of the data, that is the specific way to plot it, is not copyrightable either, but an actual figure, e.g., JPEG file, is.

Comment: @Miguel As was pointed out by Flyto, the font, scale, aspect ratio and markers are different. It is not a direct copy. That is certain.

Comment: @Miguel I can't find it. Change your original question to link to the actual figure then.

Comment: Maybe they just extracted the values from the image using one of the many tools to do so. Then they generated a new plot using this extracted data. If one looks close enough one might see that the data has changed slightly, but likely not to be noticed.

Comment: @Miguel I'm not a typesetter, but I do know that I could just provide them with an image and they'll duplicate it from scratch. I don't know how they do it, but it was certainly not by scanning the original (that leaves easily detectable traces after all). It's amazing, and I don't doubt they can duplicate your data points without the original data as well.

Comment: Having created a [pretty similar plot myself at aroundn the same time as you (fig 2.4 in my thesis, pdf page 13)](https://research-information.bristol.ac.uk/en/theses/an-optical-study-of-iiinitride-semiconductor-devices-their-thermal-properties-and-degradation-mechanisms(5fde50ad-f01f-4be1-be04-3a658e79439f).html) I know how easy it is to reproduce.  The style of yours (@Miguel) is fairly conventional and would be easy to reproduce; it may even be a default depending on what software you used

Comment: @ChrisH Then, they should have created their own, rather than edit mine (I don't understand this debate, they asked me for permission to reproduce the edited version of my figure). Unrelated: your AlInN band gap bowing parameter is obsolete. Also, my alloy band gaps are chosen from the evolution with composition from different high-symmetry points in the BZ, you can check from the discontinuity of direct-to.indirect character mid way through the curves (e.g., for ZB AlN). So I'd argue my figure is more difficult to create than yours, since it required a piece of (not too complicated) code.

Comment: @Miguel I believe they did create their own, just very similar to yours. Mine is a few years old too, and my emphasis was on the (Al)GaN side.  Plugging more complex (published) code than I used doesn't change things appreciably.

Answer (score 5):

Up-front: I am not a lawyer.

This is all complicated somewhat by both the "addon" clauses that you've tried to include, and the conversations with Elsevier in which it sounds as though you may have given them permission.

Every CC license requires users to,

> attribute the creator of licensed material, unless the creator has
>   waived that requirement, not supplied a name, or asked that her name
>   be removed. Additionally, you must retain a copyright notice, a link
>   to the license (or to the deed), a license notice, a notice about the
>   disclaimer of warranties, and a URI if reasonable.
>   (from https://creativecommons.org/faq/)

Elsevier have attributed the creator, but they have not shown any copyright notice, have not shown that the figure is CC-licensed, or provided any link. A casual reader of this book would assume that Elsevier owned the copyright on this figure, which is not correct.
On this basis, then, they are in breach of the license and hence have no right to use it.

*However*, if this were simply the CC-BY-NC license that you applied to the work, they'd be in breach anyway because they're a commercial organisation.
So the question is whether they are using the figure incorrectly under that CC license, or whether they are using it under another license or permission that you have (deliberately or otherwise) granted them in email. Or whether they are breaching copyright.

That, I fear, may be one for the lawyers.

[1] They've recreated it, not reproduced it, with some differences - but I'm fairly sure that that makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I know you wanted to avoid this but you really should consult a lawyer.

Aren't there any free or cheap consultations available where you live?

From the back and forth here with others it is obvious that we can't help you properly.

Copyright law is a giant, complex minefield best dealt with by professionals.
(expecially if you want it resolved legally binding and hopefully to your advantage if possible)

Comment: Guess why it is a minefield? Because a lot of people want to find ways and means to do dishonest things, especially due to money. After all, if you can sneak in the fake journal Chaos, Solitons & Fractals into a bundle so that you can charge more, infringing copyright is much easier since you know that small researchers don't have the money to fight back.

Comment: don't forget the patent trolls. they need to feed families too (;

Comment: No don't consult a lawyer. It's a waste of time and money. The image has been redrawn and Elsevier is far better equipped to deal with that issue than virtually anyone else. Just go on with your life.